# The named parameter 'intialWeight' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, splitview

Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'intialWeight'.
iam using package split_view

```
 intialWeight: widget.initialWeight,
```

Comment: Try fixing the typo `intial` to `initial`?

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: please share the code

Answer (score 1):

Since the version 3.0.0 the package [split_view](https://pub.dev/packages/split_view) doesn't have any parameter named **initialWeight**

> Removed fields
> minWidthSidebar/maxWidthSidebar/minHeightSidebar/maxHeightSidebar and
> initialWeight. Instead, Added the WeightLimit class so that we can
> specify the weight.

Check the [package page](https://pub.dev/packages/split_view) to see how to use the split_view with the newest versions.

You can check the complete logs [here](https://pub.dev/packages/split_view/changelog).

Answer (score 1):

Use the class "WeightLimit" instead of "initialWeight"
See the changelog of v3.0.0 on pub.dev.

https://pub.dev/packages/split_view/changelog

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any 'initialWeight' parameter in SplitView